# xtext ide not loading library

Tags: eclipse, xtext

I'm building a DSL using xtext 2.12 in eclipse oxygen following the smalljava examples in the Bettini book (2nd ed). Most everything works until I added a library as described in chapter 10. In unit tests that load the library explicitly, everything works: the library file loads, the implicit import succeeds, and I can refer to the types defined in the lib in DSL code.
However, when I now open the IDE it does not automatically load the library, and I end up with a NPE when the library tries to load implicit classes. It's clear that the loadLib method that gets called explicitly in the unit tests is not being called anywhere from the IDE because the log message is never emitted.

How do I get the IDE to load the library on startup? Specifically, I know what to call, I just don't know where to call it from in the IDE.

thanks!

Comment: how does the npe look like? did you adapt scoping?

Comment: are you sure you dont have to put the the lib is on the classpath of the model file? (export at the def / dependency at the model project)

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think I've resolved the NPE in my scoping/typing rules. I have exported the library so that it is visible, but as far as I can tell, nothing ever calls loadLib to actually load the library file into resource set. I tried to follow examples from smalljava. When I run the smalljava ide it doesn't seem to load the smalljava library either. At least I don't see the log message emitted to console when IDE starts. All of the test that do load the library call loadLib explicitly. I'm just wondering how the IDE is SUPPOSED to be calling loadLib.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the package containing the library is exported by the plugin containing the library file and the plugin containing the test model file has a dependency to the plugin containing the library file

load lib is never called by the ide. the ide direcly builds the file from the classpath of the model containing project

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "plugin containing the test model file." The use case here is that I'm opening the IDE by selecting Run As -> Eclipse Application on the dsl project. Then, I open a new dsl file in a new workspace.  The test dsl file is not contained in any plugin. But then, I would expect that it is the IDE plugin that needs to have this dependency if the library is supposed to be a default import. Is the loadLib method only intended for use in testing then?   Thanks!

Comment: no at least the first edition of the book that i have reads on the very first paragraph on the topic "org.example.smalljava;

Bettini, Lorenzo. Implementing Domain-Specific Languages with Xtext and Xtend (Kindle-Position4614). Packt Publishing. Kindle-Version. "

Comment: Now, if we run Eclipse, create a project, and add as dependency our org.example.smalljava project, the classes of mainlib.smalljava will be automatically available.

Bettini, Lorenzo. Implementing Domain-Specific Languages with Xtext and Xtend (Kindle-Positionen4611-4612). Packt Publishing. Kindle-Version.

Comment: second ed says pretty much the same thing. Ok, so apparently there must be some other bug in my implementation that is causing the implicit import to not work. When loadLib is called explicitly it works. At least if I know that loadLib isn't necessary in the IDE that gives me a clue . Not clear how to debug things that are supposed to happen implicitly...

Comment: can you show a screenshot of both manifests. where the lib is defined of the runtime tab, for the one where it is used dependencies tab

Comment: and please try a new runtime workspace. sometimes eclipse is very bad at caching

Comment: Yes, I've noticed the caching problem. Usually, just closing and reopening eclipse solves that one.

Comment: The dsl project manifest contains: Export-Package: behavior.lang, ...  Not sure what other user project needs to import this. ide? ui? I don't see those dependencies in the smalljava example.

Comment: I means this line https://github.com/LorenzoBettini/packtpub-xtext-book-2nd-examples/blob/847999a3a11d30265d75acca620f59b1d5c3fef2/org.example.smalljava.parent/org.example.smalljava/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF#L30 and something similar to this line https://github.com/LorenzoBettini/packtpub-xtext-book-2nd-examples/blob/addb6d37d81bf6daa4783342115a847b384b5c70/org.example.smalljava.parent/org.example.smalljava.generatormain.tests/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF#L9

Comment: Don’t know how you my.smalljava project looks like